# Convert Sheet to API Script commands for Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have made a pretty looking sheet called 'TEMPLATE'. Is it possible to convert this template into relevant commands, to be put into a script, that can be used to create the template?

Comment: why not just let the script copy the source template sheet?

Comment: The possibility of the template sheet going missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it public and create a script that copies the **template**, or make a script to **export the template**

```
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_GOES HERE");
 sheet.copyTo(destination);
```

where the ID is the new sheet where you want the template

Comment: This is what I have been doing and wish to replace it without the use of a template sheet. Thank you anyway.